# Fabric Twitter Kit

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

Can anyone please explain me the meaning of the following line of code? I mean how it works.

```
 final SearchService service = Twitter.getApiClient().getSearchService();
service.tweets(Search_query,null, lang,null,Search_result_type,Search_count,null,null,null,true, new Callback<Search>() {......}
```

I read the fabric docs and there it was written getSearchService() is a method of TwitterApiClient class. But whenever I am trying to use TwitterApiClient to access getSearchService(), its not showing the getSearchService() method. But using the above code,i.e., Twitter.getApiClient().getSearchService(), it works. Can anyone explain me each and every word of the Code that I have provided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This is method of TwitterApiCllient use following link :  
https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/twittercore/1.3.4/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/TwitterApiClient.html

parameter you pass inside method tweet has following means :    
tweets(query,geocode,lang,locale,resultType,count,until,sinceId, maxId, includeEntities, Callback<Search> cb) 
follow this link :
https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/twittercore/1.3.4/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/services/SearchService.html 

by default this api show only last 7 days tweet for exact query which you search

Use like this :
private void loadTweets() {


final SearchService service = Twitter.getApiClient().getSearchService();
service.tweets(SEARCH_QUERY, null, null, null, SEARCH_RESULT_TYPE, SEARCH_COUNT, null, null,
        maxId, true, new Callback<Search>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<Search> searchResult) {


            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException error) {


            }
        }
);
```